# error more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

Im not even sure what exactly my problem is from this error. Any information would be very helpful.

what i have so far:

```
def equations(specie,elements):
vectors=[]
for x in specie: 
    vector=extracting_columns(x,elements)
    vectors.append(vector)
```

When i run:

```
 equations(['OH', 'CO2','c3o3','H2O3','CO','C3H1'], 
 ['H', 'C', 'O'])
```

i get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

File "_sage_input_77.py", line 10, in 
    exec compile(u'print *support*.syseval(python, u"equations([\'OH\',   \'CO2\',\'c3o3\',\'H2O3\',\'CO\',\'C3H1\'], unel)", **SAGE_TMP_DIR**)
  File "", line 1, in

File "/sagenb/sage_install/sage-5.4-sage.math.washington.edu-x86_64-Linux/devel/sagenb-git/sagenb/misc/support.py", line 479, in syseval
    return system.eval(cmd, sage_globals, locals = sage_globals)
  File "/sagenb/sage_install/sage-5.4-sage.math.washington.edu-x86_64-Linux/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/misc/python.py", line 56, in eval
    eval(z, globals)
  File "", line 1, in

File "", line 4, in equations

File "", line 3, in extracting_columns

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

my previous functions if needed:
import re
def parse_formula(formula):
    '''Given a simple chemical formula, return a list of (element, multiplicity) tuples.

```
Example:
'H2SO4' --> [('H', 2.0), ('S', 1.0), ('O', 4.0)]


'''

return [ (elem, float(mul) if mul else 1.) for (elem, mul) in re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)', formula) ]
```

def unique_element(group):
    c=[]
    for element in group:
        piece=parse_formula(element)
        for x in piece:
            c.append(x[0])

```
return list(set(c))
```

def extracting_columns(specie, elements):
    species_vector=zeros(len(elements))
    for (el,mul) in specie:
        species_vector[elements.index(el)]=mul

```
return species_vector
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting so we can copy and paste this and try it out—or at least read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `extracting_columns` with a string like `'OH'` as the first argument, so when you try to do `for (el,mul) in specie:` it's trying to unpack the `'O'` into `(el, mul)`.

An easy way to debug this is to insert a `print` right before the offending line:

```
def extracting_columns(specie, elements):
  species_vector=zeros(len(elements))
  print(specie)
  for (el,mul) in specie:
    species_vector[elements.index(el)]=mul
  return species_vector
```

So, how is `extracting_columns` getting `'OH'`? Well, let's look at where it's called, with a couple more `print`s:

```
def equations(specie,elements):
  vectors=[]
  print(specie)
  for x in specie:
    print(x)
    vector=extracting_columns(x,elements)
    vectors.append(vector)
```

Now, when you run it, you'll see that `specie` is `['OH', 'CO2', 'c3o3', 'H2O3', 'CO', 'C3H1']`, so the first element of it is obviously `'OH'`.

As for how to fix this… well, without knowing what you're actually trying to do, it's hard to tell you how to do it. But obviously if you want to iterate over the first argument to `extracting_columns` and treat each item as a pair, you have to pass it a sequence of pairs rather than a string.

But it looks like your `parse_formula` is made specifically for turning a string like `'OH'` into a list of pairs like `[('O', 1.0), ('H', 1.0)]`. So presumably the problem is that you just forgot to call it somewhere. Maybe you want `equations` to look like this?

```
def equations(specie, elements):
  vectors=[]
  for x in specie:
    formula = parse_formula(x)
    vector=extracting_columns(formula, elements)
    vectors.append(vector)
```

This does something, without any exceptions. Whether it's what you actually want, I have no idea.

At any rate, learning how to see what's actually going on in your code and debug trivial problems is probably more important than getting the right answer here immediately.

Comment: +1, great explanation (and nice to see someone else who uses two-space indenting :) ).

Comment: @RocketDonkey: Thank whoever wrote `python-mode.el`'s auto-detect code for the two-space indenting; that was just its best guess for what to do with the OP's code for some reason. Personally, I do sometimes use two-space when posting somewhere like SO where people may not even be able to read 76 columns, but I try to stick to four-space for published and maintained code (following PEP 8).

Comment: Makes sense, good point about two-spacing here for better readability. I've found I always do four spaces here for PEP 8/public approval compliance, but I started learning Python following the Google style guide and haven't yet kicked the two-space habit (although I [obviously] don't code professionally, so the only person I bother is me). In any case, great answer as always :)